# . is converted to , when changing my app local language as spanish in android

Tags: android

Hi I am new in android and I have created an android app in which we can change app's local language. In my app language conversion working fine but I have on issue- I have a string which contain some double value like itemPrise= "20.00", which I need to parse into double, but when I use Spanish local then string value converted in itemPrice = "20,00". For English it is working fine, please help me thanks in advance. Below is my code which i used to convert local language ----

```
if (radioEnglish.isChecked()) {
                    preference.putCurrentLanguage(radioEnglish.getText().toString());
                    locale = new Locale("en");
                }

                if (radioSpanish.isChecked()) {
                    preference.putCurrentLanguage(radioSpanish.getText().toString());
                    locale = new Locale("es");
                }
                Locale.setDefault(locale);
                Configuration config = new Configuration();
                config.locale = locale;
                getActivity().getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(
                        config,
                        getActivity().getBaseContext().getResources()
                                .getDisplayMetrics());
                preference.putCurrentLanguageShortCut(locale.getDefault().toString());
                System.out.println("default lang:" + preference.getCurrentLanguageShortCut().toString());

Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
getActivity().overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
getActivity().finish();
getActivity().startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: you shouldn't store your item price in strings.xml

Comment: Hey thanks for your response, I am not adding itemPrice in string.xml, for getting item price I have an API  and I got my item price from server Using API.